# Efficiently finding the intersection of a variable number of sets of strings

Tags: java, theory, set, big-o, intersection

I have a variable number of ArrayList's that I need to find the intersection of. A realistic cap on the number of sets of strings is probably around 35 but could be more. I don't want any code, just ideas on what could be efficient. I have an implementation that I'm about to start coding but want to hear some other ideas.

Currently, just thinking about my solution, it looks like I should have an asymptotic run-time of Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Thanks for any help!

tshred

Edit: To clarify, I really just want to know is there a faster way to do it. Faster than Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! The strings are actually inside objects in an already existing array list, this is why I was leaving them in the arrays. I've never had to use the Java collections classes being mentioned but will definitely use them. I appreciate the recommendations.

Problem solved.

Comment: See also: [*How to calculate the intersection of two sets?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8882097/642706)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[`Set.retainAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) is how you find the intersection of two sets. If you use `HashSet`, then converting your `ArrayList`s to `Set`s and using `retainAll()` in a loop over all of them is actually O(n).

Comment: You only have to wrap one of the lists in a set.

Comment: It is only expected to be in O(n). It is not the worst case!

Answer (score 39):

The accepted answer is just fine; as an update : since Java 8 there is a slightly more efficient way to find the intersection of two `Set`s.

```
Set<String> intersection = set1.stream()
    .filter(set2::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The reason it is slightly more efficient is because the original approach had to add elements of `set1` it then had to remove again if they weren't in `set2`. This approach only adds to the result set what needs to be in there.

Strictly speaking you could do this pre Java 8 as well, but without `Stream`s the code would have been quite a bit more laborious.

If both sets differ considerably in size, you would prefer streaming over the smaller one.

Comment: Good note no streaming over the smaller one. It is because the streamed one is iterated, while the other (larger) set is searched (by hash for a `HashSet`, which is [O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574916/hashset-look-up-complexity)).

Comment: @bowmore Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe changing the `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` to `.forEach(e -> ...)` would be the ideal way to find the intersection of the two sets WITHOUT creating a copy of either set, or a reference to the intersection. In other words if `a = { 1, 2, 3 }` and `b = { 4, 5, 6 }` and `forEach(e -> ...)` was called, there would only ever be seven element references existing at one time. Three from set `a`, three from set `b`, and one from the callback variable `e`.

Comment: @bowmore Also to add onto what @Ondra Žižka mentioned, surely you would first check which of `set1` or `set2` has the smallest number of elements, and that set would be the one which is streamed. The remaining set would be the one referenced with `contains`.

Comment: @Hatefiend if contextually you know the sets will be relatively small, or always comparable in size, such a check would not be needed. And I say as much in my answer.

Comment: @bowmore Despite something like this rarely being the cause of a bottleneck, mistakes like this all over a codebase absolutely will be. It's unfair to dismiss the criticism, especially to those who may be viewing this who are new to programming and are looking to build good coding habits. This takes a single if statement to fix `if (set1.size() > set2.size()) ... else ...`.

Comment: @Hatefiend well, I think increasing cyclomatic complexity for something that won't gain you any performance 99% of the time, isn't a good coding habit.

Comment: @Hatefiend a small example : we have a set with all items on sale, and a set with the items in the customers basket. I'd not bother with an if. Contextually I know that most of the time the basket set will be the smaller. I will always stream over the basket, even though sometimes it may be larger than the on-sale set.
If I have a set of tweets mentioning one subject, and another set mentioning another subject both possibly counting in the millions, but both possibly being very small, yes, then I'd check.

Answer (score 19):

There is also the static method [`Sets.intersection(set1, set2)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#intersection-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-) in [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) that returns an unmodifiable view of the intersection of two sets.

Comment: Because it's a view I remember this having the unfortunate side effect of repeating intersections, so need to be careful about use case. `if (intersetionSet.size() < 1000) { doSomethingWith(intersetionSet); }`

Answer (score 7):

One more idea - if your arrays/sets are different sizes, it makes sense to begin with the smallest.

Answer (score 3):

The best option would be to use HashSet to store the contents of these lists instead of ArrayList. If you can do that, you can create a temporary HashSet to which you add the elements to be intersected (use the putAll(..) method). Do tempSet.retainAll(storedSet) and tempSet will contain the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Sort them (n lg n) and then do binary searches (lg n).

Answer (score 0):

You can use single HashSet. It's add() method returns false when the object is alredy in set. adding objects from the lists and marking counts of false return values will give you union in the set + data for histogram (and the objects that have count+1 equal to list count are your intersection). If you throw the counts to TreeSet, you can detect empty intersection early.

Answer (score 0):

In case that is required the state if 2 set has intersection, I use the next snippet on Java 8+ versions code:

```
set1.stream().anyMatch(set2::contains)
```