# HashSet look-up complexity?

Tags: java, time-complexity

A look-up operation OR `contains` for single can be `O(n)` in worst-case right ? So, for `n` elements look up in `hashSet` will be `O(n^2)`?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, but it's really the worst case: if all the elements in the `HashSet` have the same hash code (or a hash code leading to the same bucket). With a correctly written `hashCode` and a normally distributed key sample, a lookup is O(1).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but the whole reason we have HashSets is that we encounter this worst case with very, very low probability, and it's usually much faster than the guaranteed nlogn for a heap or a (self-balancing) TreeSet, or the guaranteed n^2 for an unsorted list.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in the earlier answers, the lookup time complexity is O(1). To make make sure that it's true, just look into a source code for `contains()`:

```
...

private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;

...

public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return map.containsKey(o);
}

...
```

As you can see, it uses a `HashMap` object internally, to check if your object exists.

Then, if we take a look into an implementation of `contains()` for `HashMap`, then we'll see the code as follows:

```
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getNode(hash(key), key) != null;
}
```

`getNode()` searches for a node based on a key hash value and a key value. Please note that `hash(key)` has an O(1) time complexity.

And finally, for `getNode()`:

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; 
    Node<K,V> first, e; 
    int n; 
    K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The most important part is basically the first inner `if` block:

```
...
        if (first.hash == hash &&
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
...
```

If hashes of your object `key` and that of the first element `first` are equal, and objects themselves are equal (obviously!), then `first` is the object we're looking for, and this is O(1).

As you can see, it all depends on the implementation of the hash function - if it's good, then it will mostly assign different buckets for different key objects. If not, then several key objects may reside in the same bucket, and so we will need to do a lookup in the bucket itself to find the right key as seen here:

```
...
        if (first instanceof TreeNode)
            return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
        do {
            if (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return e;
...
        } while ((e = e.next) != null);
```

However, even in this case, if your bucket is a `TreeNode` it is O(log(k))  (k - number of elements in the bucket) because it's a balanced binary search tree. If not (the `else` block), it's O(k). But again, this will happen rarely (or maybe even never for some types of objects), and so the average time complexity for one call of the `contains` method will remain O(1). Obviously, if you perform `n` calls then the total time complexity will be linear.

Answer (score -26):

lookp takes O(c)

c = constant value

Comment: The notation O (big o) already implies a constant coefficient, hence the O(1).