# Swap-search algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array A of n integers. I also have an array B of k (k < n) integers. What I need is that any integer from array A that appears in array B to be increased by 3.

If I go with the most obvious way, I get to n*k complexity.
Array A cannot (must not) be sorted.

Is there a more efficient way of achieveing this?

Comment: Maybe, what are the rage of the integers (`n`)

Comment: @omainegra I think they're pretty mad.

Comment: Array A is/can be sorted or not?

Comment: Array A can't be sorted. I mean, of course it can, it's an array of integers, but it would break the rest of the program.

Comment: copy A to `newarray` using `var newArray = new int[A.length]; System.arrayCopy(A,0,newArray,0,A.length)`. Now you can sort the identical copy of A just fine. Just because you can't sort A doesn't mean you can't sort your data.

Comment: What are the sizes and ranges of A and B, and can B be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more efficient way of achieveing this?

Yes: put the elements of `B` into a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Loop over `A` and, if the element you're on is contained in the set, increase it by 3. This will have O(n + k) complexity.

For instance:

```
Set<Integer> bSet = new HashSet<>(B.length);

for (int a : B)  // O(k)
    bSet.add(a);

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {  // O(n)
    if (bSet.contains(a[i]))
        a[i] += 3;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, creating hashset with B has O(k*logk) complexity and looping over A has O(n*logk) complexity, so at total it is O(n*logk + k*logk) which is O(logk(n+k))

Comment: @libik That's not true. Adding to a `HashSet` is a constant-time process. Containment tests are also O(1), and so is incrementing. So the second loop is linear in n, while the first is linear in k. Hence, the overall complexity *is* O(n + k).

Comment: Well ok, you get the point :). However it works only for small instances. The complexity of hashset operations grows with huge instances to the values I wrote...

Comment: of course not. Only if you have infinite memory, then you can works with constant time. Otherwise not. The hash in reality means, that in average case, your problem is multiplied as much as current hash differences. So the complexity is DEVIDED by the number of possible hash solution. The real hash "contains" value is n/k, where k is big constant, still constant. For little instances the k > n, so it is working -almost- in constant time. (however if you are unlucky, you can reach the O(n) complexity, but the chances is too small to be considered as problem)

Comment: bSet.contains complexity is not 1, and .add also is not 1

Comment: @IlyaBursov They absolutely are. There may be an amortized worst case cost of O(n) but the overall complexity is still O(1).

Comment: @arshajii they are absolutely not, especially checked oracle java sources, you spend time on hash calculation during add, then you go through whole array to replace value, during contains you do almost the same

Comment: @IlyaBursov Please cite your source, because what you're saying is completely preposterous. `hashCode` of `Integer` is O(1) - all it does is return a value, there is *virtually no* time spent on the hash calculation here because there's nothing to calculate: the hash of an `Integer` is its value. And you don't "go through the whole array" - that's the whole point of using a hash table.

Comment: int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key);
        for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
             e != null;
             e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                return e;
        }

you still have to check array if there are collisions, in general way - there will be, this is why you cannot say "always O(n+k)", it can be in best cases, but in worst case you can have O(n*k)

Comment: @IlyaBursov Yes but that doesn't factor in to the complexity. The entire purpose of using a hash map is to have relatively constant lookup and addition times. The worst case you describe would mean that most integers hashed to a singe location (or a few common locations), which is simply too rare to even worry about (especially since we're sizing our table appropriately). Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574916/hashset-look-up-complexity) question.

Comment: @arshajii for loop contribute to complexity, I understand sense of hashmaps, and understand why they are can be sometimes faster/better, I just arguing with "always be O(n+k)" - this is not true in general case

Comment: @IlyaBursov If you want to split hairs, you can find some absurd case for which that's not true. But we *would* still call this process O(n + k). And yes, of course the loops contribute, they're the whole reason the process is linear and not constant.

Comment: @arshajii I don't like call it "split hairs", but maybe so, if we're speaking about algorithm complexity, we should always take in account all cases, if we do "contains" for each n, and we have worst case, we will have o(n*k) and in real projects with big data, according to murphy's law - it will be o(n*k) :)

Comment: @IlyaBursov I don't think you appreciate how astonishingly rare the case you're describing is. Integers already have a perfect hash function: there are no collisions. The only thing that could cause two of them to be put in the same spot would be the modulus operation that has to be done in order to fit them into the table. Even if we have 5-10-15 of them in the same spot, the complexity is still O(n + k). What you're describing is when we have 100s if not 1000s in the same places, at which point O(n + k) is no longer an accurate estimate. We have better things to worry about than this...

Comment: Also, I ask that you rethink your downvote, as I don't believe the reason behind it is justified.

Comment: @arshajii I agree that it's quite rare situation, but if we have big data flow - these rare situations become commons, I know it very well, this is why I insist on proper understanding of what going on inside hashtables, why are they not O(1), and what additional overhead can be (for very small data for example) if we have to tune up to cpu tacts

Comment: @IlyaBursov While I still completely disagree, do you have a better solution than this? By the way if hash tables are not O(1) in contains and add (which they are), then what are they?

Comment: @IlyaBursov Let me rephrase the second question: your claim is that `HashSet`'s contain and add methods are indeed not O(1) but rather O(n). If that's the case why would anyone ever use a `HashSet`? Why not just use an `ArrayList` for everything?

Comment: @arshajii no, my claim that hashmap has O(1) only when hashmap capacity is enough to store all possible values (which is rare situation), for capacities less than range we get O(C) where C>1 and can go up to N in case of capacity=1 (which is the same rare situation as when capacity is enough), so, in two rare cases we have O(1) and O(n), but for all other we have something between it, which we must be taken in account and find balance between memory consumption and performance

Comment: @IlyaBursov The point is we generally (99% of the time) have something that does not depend on `n`, meaning we consider it to be O(1) (your O(C) is really O(1) by the definition of big-O). If you don't believe me, test this answer with a few random array lengths yourself, and you'll see a linear relationship, I guarantee it.

Comment: @arshajii C depends on N, because in general C=(max(N)-min(N))/capacity, in case of min(N) = 0, and max(N) = N, we have N/capacity, so we have O(N) complexity if we omit all constants, again - I understand that it is very rare situation, and we usually can speak about O(1), as we select capacity to be close to N, but I want to stress that this O(1) is not so constant, as it can be imagine

Comment: @IlyaBursov Okay, so what's the issue with my answer? Why the down vote? Surely it's not the subtlety that this will not *always* be *perfectly* O(n + k) even though in most real-world and imaginable cases it will be almost exactly. I'm just trying to understand your viewpoint better.

Comment: @arshajii as I point earlier - just don't tell that this algorithm is always O(N+K), it is not true, it can be close to it in particular cases, but not always, and I think it is important for this particular question as OP asking about "efficient way", and to compare it - he must know why O(N+K) of your proposal is bigger than O(N+K) for "infinity memory situation", for such "delicate matters" I prefer to write: O(K + N*K/capacity), so O(K+N*C) >= O(K+N), and of course hashmap solution with proper capacity better than straight n*k and quite often better than n*log2(k)

Comment: @IlyaBursov Well, I'll have to disagree with you on that. It's perfectly reasonable to think of this as an O(n + k) operation. If you time this for a few arbitrary arrays I'm certain the results will support this assertion. As I said: can there be example arrays for which O(n + k) is no longer accurate given our hash table based algorithm? Of course, there *can* be cases like this, but they're so obscure and rare that there is simply no point in considering them when doing the complexity calculation. For all practical purposes, this is O(n + k).

Comment: @arshajii so do I, I agree with wiki: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) that search in hashtable usually between O(1) and O(N) - and this is the only real fact about it, so O(K + N*X), where 1<=X<=K, of course we can perform some statistical research, and find out how often X is closer to 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

if array B can be sorted - then solution is obvious, sort it, then you can optimize "contains" to be log2(K), so your complexity will be N*log2(k)

if you cannot sort array B - then the only thing is straight forward N*K

UPDATE

really forgot about bitmask, if you know that you have only 32 bit integers, and have enough memory - you can store huge bitmask array, were "add" and "contains" always will be O(1), but of course it is needed only for very special performance optimizations

Answer (score 0):

If your integers are in a range that you can create and array with the length of the greatest value (for instance `0 <= A[i] and B[i] <= 65535`) then you can do this

```
boolean [] constains = new boolean[65535];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++){
    constains[B[i]] = true;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (constains[A[i]]){
        A[i] += 3;
    }
}
```

Which is O(n + k)