# How to make java nested loops efficient

Tags: java, arrays, loops, time-complexity

I currently need to code a program that does a pairwise comparison to find matching pairs in an int list, but the only way I can think of doing it is through a nested for loop. Is there a way to make the time complexity O(n) instead of the O(n^2) of a nested for loop?

```
int[] arr = new int[n];
int total = 0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
            total++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may start with `j=i+1` is not you will compare each bow with itself and have at least `n` pairs even if all are different

Comment: Your question is about time complexity, but you tagged it with **memory**-efficient.  Was that a mistake?

Comment: There isn't a fixed number in the list. I've edited to time-complexity instead thanks!

Comment: not sure i get what the code do for example if the array is full of single number let us say all element equal 1 and let us say the array length is 5 then total would be 10 is that what you looking for or it should be 5 ?

Comment: Yup! 5 is what i'm looking for. Just doing a pairwise comparison for similar int.

Comment: @Gbeck then your code does not do that your code will make total be 10 and another question if number x repeated 3 times and number y repeated 5 so should total be 8 or what ? (please notice x != y )

Comment: What I was intending to do is get 5 pairs. Since x will have 2 pairs of the same int and y will have 3 pairs of the same int. Total = 2 +3 = 5

Comment: check saka1029 answer and see if  that what you looking for

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are only worried about the count. So, if modifying an array is not an issue then, apply quick sort in O(nlog(n)) and then count the neighbours in O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HashSet` which has `O(1)` complexity of `contains` method - because `hashCode` of `Integer` value in Java is well distributed (it's just a value of the `Integer`) you should have constant complexity always

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet();
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(set.contains(arr[i])) {
        total++;
    } else {
        set.add(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Read more here:

- [HashSet look-up complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574916/hashset-look-up-complexity)

---

There's also one additional algorithm that could be implemented here but it require some data limitations (due to the max length of array on your machine).

You could just create an int array `yourarray` initialized with `0` with a length of `max(arr) + 1`. Then you are iterating over `arr` every time executing `yourarray[arr[i]]++` and then you are iterating over `yourarray` checking where the value is greater than `1` - if it this then it means that this value has to repeat

Answer (score 1):

O(n) solution.
Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3};
    int total = arr.length - (int)IntStream.of(arr).distinct().count();
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a HashSet to resolve this problem. The HashSet in JAVA doesn't allow insert into a duplicate element. So you can use it to making the time complexity become O(n).

```java
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Integer total = 0;
        for (int x: arr)
        {
            if (!set.add(x))
            {
               total++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just to further explain, for example, is the array is {0,0,0}, there will be 3 pairs, because the 1st and 2nd is a pair, 1st and 3rd and 2nd and 3rd, so there will be 3 pairs