# Comparing two Strings in java and identifying duplicate words

Tags: java, string, duplicates

I'm trying be able to compare two Strings and identify duplicate words. For example;

```
String1 = "Hello, my name is John."
String2 = "Can you tell me your name please?"
```

Comparing String1 and String2 would return the word; "name".

I know it is possible to split these two strings into an array of words, and then iterate over each word of each String in a 2-D array. However this is computationally expensive at O(n^2) and I was wondering if there is a faster way of doing this?

Thanks.

EDIT: Changed the example for clarity.

Comment: So, you also want punctuation removed, then?

Comment: @fge Sorry, failed to notice that example wouldn't work. I have changed it now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After getting the strings to word arrays:

You can add all the elements in the first array to a hashmap and then scan the second array to see if each of the elements exists in the hashmap. Since access time to a hashmap is O(1), this will be O(n+m) time complexity.

If you do not want to use extra space, you can sort both of the arrays in O(nlogn) and then compare the items in O(n+m) which would give you O(nlogn) in total.

Comment: Okay I'll give this a go and report back. Thanks

Comment: The hashmap solution is probably the best, just bear in mind that the speed difference can be much more significant for longer texts.

Comment: @jedrus07 Yes, that is absolutely right, I just wanted to present another option better than O(n^2)

Comment: Okay this works well, thank you. I'm going to try the other answer below as well and see if it runs any faster before I accept this answer

Answer (score 6):

One simple solution is to use the `Sets.intersection` method of Guava's `Sets`. It is pretty easy:

```
String s1 = "Hello, my name is John.";
String s2 = "Can you tell me your name?";
Splitter splitter = Splitter.onPattern("\\W").trimResults().omitEmptyStrings();
Set<String> intersection = Sets.intersection(//
        Sets.newHashSet(splitter.split(s1)), //
        Sets.newHashSet(splitter.split(s2)));
System.out.println(intersection);
```

Output:

```
[name]
```

You can also find more information on algorithms to detect Set intersection on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574311/efficiently-compute-intersection-of-two-sets-in-java).

Comment: Should the Splitter object be a StringSplitter? Splitter isn't being recognised.

Comment: BTW I'm using `Guava 13.0.1` for this.

Comment: Okay. I'm just gonna go with the answer above as it doesn't require any external libraries and I was able to get it working at a fairly fast speed. Thanks for your help anyway.