# Efficient way of finding intersection of 5 Sets

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, set

I have 5 sets which has numeric values. I am interested in finding the intersection of all 5 sets.

Right now, I am thinking of the following

```
Do a Collections.sort() on all 5 sets
```

Find the shortest set and do a

```
shortestSet.retainAll(otherSet);
```

on all the other sets.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: I think that would be an efficient way indeed (assuming you mean to sort the *sizes* of the sets)

Comment: Almost dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574311/efficiently-compute-intersection-of-two-sets-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently compute Intersection of two Sets in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574311/efficiently-compute-intersection-of-two-sets-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution looks right to me, if we understand that when you write `Collections.sort()`  you are sorting the list of sets, according to their sizes. The rationale would be that, if we are going to use `set1.retainAll(set2)` (and if the sets are `HashSet`s) each intersection running time should be roughly linear on the number of elements of `set1`. So it makes sense to start with the smallest one.

Comment: In addition to sorting the sets by size before calling retainAll(),  would it make a difference if we sort the sets itself ?

Comment: @Skynet: No (if you are talking about sorting content of the sets).

Comment: @Skynet: No. Further, sets do not have order. ( you `sort` lists, not sets)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is fine. There would be no need to sort the numbers before calling the retainAll method though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
static <E> Sets.SetView<E> intersection(Set<E> set1, Set<?> set2)
```

In [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)