# What is the best optimized way to find if a list contains every element of another list?

Tags: java, list, time-complexity

I have two list:

```
List<String> firstList = new LinkedList<String>();
List<String> secondList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

I want to know if every element of a list is contained by the other list.
A possible solution could be:

```
public boolean function(List<String> first, List<String> second)
{
first = firstList;
second = secondList
for (String item : firstList)
    {
            for (String elem : secondList)
            {
                if(elem.compareTo(item)!=0)
                return false;
            }
    }
 return true;
 }
```

As we can see, the time is quadratic. Is there a way to do it better?

Comment: Why not just use [`containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-)?

Comment: You can use one foreach for firstList and `contains` method of list.

Comment: @resueman Because `constainsAll` uses linear search.

Comment: Your approach will often returns `false` when it should return `true`, because you return `false` too early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an O(n*m) implementation with O(1) space requirements; you could make an O(n+m) implementation with O(m) space requirements by adding elements of the first list to `HashSet<String>`, and then verifying that all elements of the second list are present:

```
Set<String> firstSet = new HashSet<String>(firstList);
for (String elem : secondList) {
    if(!firstSet.contains(item)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

or even better

```
return new HashSet<>(firstList).containsAll(secondList);
```

(thanks, [bradimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5884788/bradimus)!)

**Note:** Your approach uses sub-optimal comparison mechanism: rather than calling `compareTo`, you could call `equals`, because you do not need to check if the word is alphabetically before or after.

Another problem is that your approach will often returns `false` when it should return `true`, because you return `false` too early.

Comment: Good observations on the OP's solution.  I believe yours could be shortened to `return new HashSet<>(firstList).containsAll(secondList);` without loss of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean function(List<String> first, List<String> second) {
    return (second.size() == first.size() && first.containsAll(second))
}
```

Comment: This checks that the two lists contain *exactly the same elements*, not that the bigger list contains all elements of the smaller list.

Comment: @SirCelsius is right... But it is probably only the variation on `containsAll()` method usage... 
For bigger list it could be something like this `return first.size() >= second.size() ? first.containsAll(second) : second.contains(first)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether one or both lists change regulary you may find it more efficient to use `HashSet<String>` for one that changes rarely.

See [Set operations: union, intersection, difference, symmetric difference, is subset, is superset](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`!Collections.disjoint(list1, list2);`

Or you can use `containsAll`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7574395/3465375) that I believe can address your question.

The idea is basically to use two `Set` and to calculate the size of their intersection.

I believe that if you can afford to use `Set` instead of `List` so you can save time on `contains`. You will have a complexity of `o(n)` whatever happens.

---

**Edit**

If you care about matching duplicates in your input Lists the above solution may not be efficient. You may want to be careful about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return first.containsAll(second);
```