# performance finding elements in collection

Tags: java, collections

I have two collections

The first contains all the elements.

The second contains the elements that I am interested in from the first collection.

The data is in an alphabetical format:

AAA

AA.12.AA

BBB.234.B1

CC.89

…

The first collection contains around 300.000 records roughly.

Now, if I want to get 10 thousand records from the first collection it is taking up to 40 seconds to find them.

Collection types: firstColl = ArrayList  , secondColl = List

Action: I iterate all elements in the firstColl and for every element I check if the secondColl has the element in it.

Just want to know if anyone knows a most performance way to do it by using maybe BigList, Streams,...

CODE:

```
List<RegionPolygon> regionPolygons = new ArrayList<>();

for (RegionPolygon regionPolygon: result) {

    if (regionsArray.contains(regionPolygon.getRegionRef())) {
        regionPolygons.add(regionPolygon);
    }
}
```

Note: RegionPolygon has a property which is a String with a very long value (more than 2000 thousand characters easily, although I am not using that property to check if it is the region that I am looking for). Just wanted to say this cause I don't know if this is part of the problem.

result = firstColl

regionsArray = secondColl

Thanks,

Comment: *"Now, if I want to get 10 thousand records from the first collection it is taking up to 40 seconds to find them."* - how? What do you do, what 10 thousand records? What code have you used that takes 40 seconds?

Comment: plz give us some code to show what the data and data structures you are using

Comment: Are those collections sorted in any way?

Comment: Updated! @Aaron they come alphabetically sorted as they come from the DB.

Comment: @Aisatora Can't you do the selection on your DB instead?

Comment: [This article](http://www.learn4master.com/algorithms/union-and-intersection-of-two-sorted-arrays-java) describes well how to take advantage of the order of the lists to compute their intersection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574311/efficiently-compute-intersection-of-two-sets-in-java

Comment: It would be a lot easier if `secondColl` were a `Set` or if `firstColl` were a `Map` from `regionRef`->`RegionPolygon`

Comment: Hi @MarkJeronimus, This is one of the examples that I want to try out... I will detail the results, thanks

Comment: @Ivar I can but I have all the data sorted in memory cause I will have to access the same set of data over and over and hitting the database each time does not sound efficient to me. Thanks,