# returning specific values from a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a dictionary of terms `dictonery/AB.txt` and a large text file `dictonery/annotate.txt`.

I want to know which dictionary terms in `AB.txt` are in the `annotate.txt` file.

Here is my code so far:

```
 String fileString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("dictonery/AB.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

 String entireFileText = new Scanner(new File("dictonery/annotate.txt")).useDelimiter("\\A").next();

 map.put(fileString, "m");

 for (String key : map.keySet()) {
     if(fileString.contains(key)) {
         System.out.print(key);
     }
 }
```

At the moment the whole dictionery is returned. How can I get it to be the specific terms in the `annotator.txt` file?

Comment: `Scanner.next` method accepts regular expressions, have you tried that ?

Comment: You're just adding the whole file to the map. You need to break it up and add it. Why a map though? a map of what to what? Are you just trying to get a list of all unique words in the file? or are you trying to map words to their descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that might help:

- Since you don't need the values in your `Map`, I would use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (specifically [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)).
- Use [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) to read individual words instead of the entire file at once
- Your check for `fileString.contains(key)` is pretty inefficient, and it will also return `true` for partial matches (if your dictionary has the word "do", it will also match "dog"). It will also print matching words multiple times.

Personally, I would create two sets, read both files the same way, and then [calculate their intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882097/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-sets). If you want sorted output (probably not a requirement, but generally nice), you could make the `Set` that you iterate over a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a map.

1. Read in your annotate.txt as your `fileString`
2. Read in your AB.txt file using a loop like this:

   ```
   File file = new File("data.txt");

   try {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
       while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
           String line = scanner.nextLine();
           // do something like fileString.contains(line) here
       }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
3. In the while loop, check if the `fileString` contains the `line` (which should contain the token it just read from your file).

This assumes that you have a single token per line.

Comment: Why use `nextLine()` (and assume a particular format of the input) instead of `next()`, which works as long as each word is whitespace-separated? Also, why bother catching the exception if you're just going to print the stack trace?

Comment: @Brendon - This is just meant to be a general example of using a Scanner.  The OP did not provide a sample of their AB.txt file or annotate.txt file so I am trying to lead them in the right direction based on the information they provided.  Based on their file format, they absolutely could code it like what you state.  I originally was going to provide a link to a tutorial on Scanner but figured I would provide a basic example instead.