# Intersection of multiple sets (as collections)

Tags: java, intersection

How can you find the intersection of multiple (more than two) sets in Java?

`retainAll` by itself wont work since I need the ability to get the intersection between more than just two sets

Comment: Any code you can show us?

Comment: @SamM oh, i posted this as an answer.  I didn't realize I had to wait 2 days to accept my answer.  I'm new to this stuff and this is my first time checking the "answer your own question" box.  hope I'm not mis-using it.

Comment: why was this downvoted

Comment: the question looks like you didn't do any research before asking, this usually is a downvote-bait, but since you answered it yourself, this is wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to calculate the intersection of two sets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882097/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-sets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static <T> Collection<T> getIntersection(Collection<T>... sets) {

    Collection<T> firstSet;

    if (sets == null || sets.length == 0 || (firstSet = sets[0]) == null)
        return Collections.<T>emptySet();

    Collection<T> intersection = new HashSet(firstSet);

    for (Collection c : sets) {
        if (c == null) 
            return Collections.<T>emptySet();
        intersection.retainAll(c);
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

Comment: This may work, but it's reinventing the wheel. There is a built-in method `retainAll()` that does the same job.

Comment: thanks @aetheria, i changed the answer to implement retainAll

Comment: 2 other tips: if you use varargs, i don't think, that it (`sets`) can be `null`. You should check `sets.length != 0` and maybe a `null` check on the elements of `sets`. Also, It's a good practice, not to return `null`, when you promised to return a `Collection`! Return `Collections.<T>emptyList()` or `Collections.<T>emptySet()`, or throw an `Exception`, if you think, that a `null` value is a game breaker.

Comment: @bali182 cool, thank you! i edited per yr suggestions.  also, it seems to work okay with a `null` `sets` input

Comment: Doesn't getIntersection() simply return what was passed to it? That's what it does when I use it. Say your first set in the passed collection is (11,12) and other sets are (1,3,4,5), etc and not containing any elements contained in the first set, then wouldn't using retainAll() result in an empty result set? As the javaDoc for retainall() states "...removes from this set all of its elements that are not contained in the specified collection..." so if there is no match for the first 2 sets then all subsequent  uses of retainAll() will result in an empty set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Set's `retainAll(other)` method which retains only items that are in both sets. It alters the original set, so you may want to take a copy of the set first (use the appropriate constructor).