# How do you compare the content of two hash sets?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, set, hashset

I am trying to find items that occur in two sets. I have to use Sets, that is why I am not using any other libraries, etc.

My code is the following:

```
public static void intersection (ArrayList<Integer>s1, ArrayList<Integer>s2) {
      HashSet <Integer> all = new HashSet<Integer>();
      HashSet <Integer> both = new HashSet<Integer>();

            for (int i=0; i<s1.size(); i++)
                all.add(s1.get(i));

            for (int x=0; x<s2.size(); x++) {
                if ((!(all.add(s2.get(x)))) && (((all.contains(s2.get(x)))))) {
                    both.add(s2.get(x));
                        }
            }
            System.out.println("intersection - "+ both);
}
```

The arraylists contain the following values:

> s1: 4 5 5 6 76 7 7 8 8 8 8 8
>
> s2: 23 3 4 3 5 3 53 5 46 46 4 6 5 3 4

However, the output is the following:

> 3, 4, 5, 6, 46

My desire output is:

> 4, 5, 6

I understand that it is adding 3 and 46 because to the `ArraySet` both because those are elements present in the s2 `ArrayList` but not in s1. However, I added `all.contains(s2.get(x))` to make sure that the number added is present in s1 or `HashSet` all. Why is not working?

Comment: it's for an assignment so I have to write like that.. @ReutSharabani

Comment: have a look at retainAll() or just have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882097/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-sets

Comment: please format your code properly. Some comments: a) you can re-use `int i` in the second `for`-loop, b) why do you add everything from `s1` to `all`? As far as I understand, you only need the intersection, not the union.

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se with using HashSet with Integers. But with `Comparable` values, using a TreeSet has its advantages (and disadvantages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this

```
public static void intersection (ArrayList<Integer>s1, ArrayList<Integer>s2)
{
    HashSet <Integer> intersect = new HashSet<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i<s1.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s2.contains(s1.get(i))) intersect.add(s1.get(i));

    }

    System.out.println("intersection - "+ intersect);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program could be reduced to

```
Set<Integer> both = new HashSet<>(s1);
both.retainAll(s2);
System.out.println("intersection - " + both);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, checking for presence in the all list like you are doing here is wrong, as you could have already added this value off of the s2 list.

```
 if ((!(all.add(s2.get(x)))) && (((all.contains(s2.get(x)))))) {
```

You need to check it against the contents of s1. The question is whether you just want to call

```
 s1.contains (s2.get(x))
```

or use a possibly more efficient solution like converting s1 to a TreeSet first, or sorting s1 and doing a binary search