# Minimum number true from a set

Tags: java

For example let assume that I defined set of 5 integers.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 7;
int c = 8;
int d = 9;
int e = 10;
```

Now on the fly i receive five values a1,b1,c1,d1,e1. These can have any values but not limited to the ones i defined.

I want to return true if at-least 3 values i received on fly matches with the ones i defined.

```
Public String atleastThreeMatches(){
(a1=a && b1 = b && c1 = c) || .....
}
```

Doing something like above wont be feasible, if i have to match large number of values.

Is there a function in Java or anything which can accomplish this?

Comment: Use a counter.  `if (something matches) count++`; `if (something else matches) count++`; etc.  Then `if (count >= 3) ...`.  If you can put all the things you're matching in an array, so that you can do this with a loop, that would be much better.

Comment: Did you mean *Java* or *Javascript*.  I ask because of the `function` keyword.

Comment: It would be easier for you if you define the 5 integers in an array like `int[] ints = new int[] {5,7,8,9,10};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you meant to declare your variables.  Either in the class declaration, parameters to the method, or on the stack.  But the general logic is this:

```
boolean atLeastThreeMatches()
{
    int count = 0;
    count += (a == a1)?1:0;
    count += (b == b1)?1:0;
    count += (c == c1)?1:0;
    count += (d == d1)?1:0;
    count += (e == e1)?1:0;
    return (count >= 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Intersection of Sets

Learn about the Java Collections framework. In particular, the `Set` interface and implementations such as `HashSet`.

You need an intersection of `Set` objects as discussed on [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8882097). You can work with the `Set::retainAll` method.

Or for convenience, look at adding the Google Guava library to your project. That library offers a handy set intersection method.

Look at the size of the resulting intersection to see if is more or less than three.

Of course you would have to use objects like `Integer` rather than the primitive `int`.