# Compare two sets' elements

Tags: java, data-structures, set, key, hashtable

I have two sets, each one contains Words(String)

```
Set <String> Set1= words1.keySet();
Set <String> Set2= words2.keySet();
```

I know the set is unordered , but i want to check if the First 5 elements of the both sets are equal or not , then check the next 5 elements ..  etc
any one can guide me ..

Comment: What do you mean by `first element` of Set? Set is not ordered.

Comment: I know this , i said this as an example.
i want to know how many elements in both sets are equals
@vinS

Comment: @YousefAhmad you didn't say it's an example; and even so, what are you then looking for?

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about how to find the [intersection of two sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882097/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-sets)?

Comment: `keysDoc1.equals(keysDoc2)`.

Comment: i want to check the elements of both sets , and count how many elements of the sets are equals @AndyTurner

Comment: but this will return Boolean which is not good for me @AndyTurner

Comment: He wants the common elements in both `Set`s I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should DIY but here's the code:

```
    int count = 0;
            for(String s : keysDoc1)
            {
                if(keysDoc2.contains(s))
                    count++;
            }
//print count;
```

**EDIT:**
Alternative approach

```
Set<String> c = keysDoc1;

        c.retainAll(keysDoc2); //remove uncommon elements from c

        System.out.println(c.size());
```