# how to remove unique elements from arrayList

Tags: java, collections

I have two lists, in one list values are 1,2,3

another list 2,3

I want to remove the values which are not matched in both lists.

2 and 3 are matched in both lists then 1 is not mached in both lists so I want to remove that value.

```
List original = [1,2,3];

List dummy = [2,3];
```

Comment: What if `dummy` have values that aren't in `original`? Do you want to get those too?

Comment: What have you tried up to now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `Set` to achieve your requirement.
Use `retainAll()`  defined in `Collection` that any `List` implementation implements such as :

```
List<Integer> original = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
List<Integer> dummy = Arrays.asList(2,3);

original.retainAll(dummy);
System.out.println(original);
```

Output :

> [2, 3]

Answer (score 3):

If it's possible to use sets instead, then you can just get the intersection between the sets ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882126/723090)):

```
Set<String> s1;
Set<String> s2;
s1.retainAll(s2); // s1 now contains only elements in both sets
```

Of course with sets you can't have duplicates and you'll lose ordering.

Comment: A `LinkedHashSet` even would maintain the insert order. And duplicates seem not to be conceived. So this is indeed a fine solution.

Comment: This answer changes the requirement (if the two lists contain `1`, it is not asked that we have only a single 1 as result) and it changes also the elements order. The question is "I want to remove the values which are not matched in both lists."

Comment: @davidxxx That was already clearly stated in the answer, but thanks for emphasizing

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8+ you can use :

```
original.removeIf(a -> !dummy.contains(a));
```

---

Here is an example with Java 10

```
var original = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
var dummy = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2, 4, 3));

original.removeIf(a -> !dummy.contains(a));

System.out.println(original);
->[2, 3, 4]
```