# Optimizing If- else if- else statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization, logic

In doing a lotto checker program, where one of the constraints is to ***not use loops***, or ***data structures like arrays, lists etc*** I've written the following piece of code to check if the 3 entries given by the user (*draw1, draw2, draw3*) are equal to any of the 7 random numbers generated by the program (*random1, random2, random3, ...*).

```
if (random1==draw1 || random2==draw1 || random3==draw1 || random4==draw1|| random5==draw1
    || random6==draw1 || random7==draw1)
    {
        if(random1==draw2 || random2==draw2 || random3==draw2 || random4==draw2|| random5==draw2
        || random6==draw2 || random7==draw2)
        {
            if(random1==draw3 || random2==draw3 || random3==draw3 || random4==draw3|| random5==draw3
            || random6==draw3 || random7==draw3)
            {
                str = str +'\n' + "The following 3 matches were found:" +'\n'+ draw1 + " " + draw2
                + " " + draw3 ;
            }else
            {
                str = str + '\n' + "The following 2 matches were found:" + '\n' + draw1 + " " + draw2;
            }
        }else if (random1==draw3 || random2==draw3 || random3==draw3 || random4==draw3|| random5==draw3
        || random6==draw3 || random7==draw3)
        {
            str = str + '\n' + "The following 2 matches were found:" + '\n' + draw1 + " " + draw3 ;
        }
        else
        {
            str = str + '\n' + "The following 1 matches were found:" + '\n' + draw1;
        }
    }else if (random1==draw2 || random2==draw2 || random3==draw2 || random4==draw2|| random5==draw2
    || random6==draw2 || random7==draw2)
    {
        if(random1==draw3 || random2==draw3 || random3==draw3 || random4==draw3|| random5==draw3
        || random6==draw3 || random7==draw3)
        {
            str = str + '\n' + "The following 2 matches were found:" + '\n' + draw2 + " " + draw3;
        }
        else
        {
            str = str + '\n' + "The following 1 matches were found:" + '\n' + draw2;
        }
    }
    else if (random1==draw3 || random2==draw3 || random3==draw3 || random4==draw3|| random5==draw3
    || random6==draw3 || random7==draw3)
    {
        str = str + '\n' + "The following 1 matches were found:" + '\n' + draw3;
    }
    else
    {
        str = str + '\n' + "The following 0 matches were found:" ;
    }
```

How can I go about optimizing this and most importantly will the optimization only increase readability or will it contribute to the efficiency of the program?

Comment: are you allowed to use native methods like `ArrayList.contains(...)`?

Comment: Put the random numbers into a set, put the draw numbers into another set, then find the size of the intersection. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882097/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-sets

Comment: Sorry about that, but I edited the question now. We're not allowed to use any data structures, so no sets or arrays or lists.

Comment: If you do not use loop or data structures like `Set`, you will write `7^3=343` permutations of `if-else` blocks. I don't think you would like to do so.

Comment: Why would I have to write 343 permutations of if-else blocks? I'm confused.

Comment: @muetzenflo nope

Answer (score 0):

Use sets, this will improve readabilty.

```
    Set<Integer> luckyNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    //Add your numbers to the set
    //Integer i = ...
    //luckyNumbers.add(i);

    Set<Integer> drawNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    //Integer i = ...
    //drawNumbers.add(i);

    Set<Integer> matchNumbers = new HashSet<>(luckyNumbers);
    matchNumbers.retainAll(drawNumbers);
    //In matchNumbers will be the intersection of the previous sets.
    //There you can get the size of the intersection set or its content to show the
    //matches
```

If you want to use a loop for this part you can do something like this:

```
System.out.println("Number of matches: " + matchNumbers.size());

        for(Integer matchNumber : matchNumbers){

            System.out.println("Match number: " + matchNumber);

        }
```

Comment: We're not supposed to use loops! Also, I didn't mention it before (sorry!) but we're not allowed to use data structures like sets or lists either.

Comment: honestly...tell your prof that this is just stupid and will not teach you anything that you will need at any point in your career. Except you want to become a prof ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static boolean equalsAny(int base, int... comparisons) {
    for (int c : comparisons)
        if (base == c)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

and you can rewrite

```
 if (random1 == draw1 || random2 == draw1 || random3 == draw1 || random4 == draw1 || random5 == draw1
     || random6 == draw1 || random7 == draw1) {
```

to

```
if (equalsAny(draw1, random1, random2, random3, random4, random5, random6, random7)) {
```