# collection framework : operation on two collection object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There are two collections :-

c1 = which include all female employee

c2= all employee whose age greater than 40(age>40).

How can i find all female employee whose age greater than 40?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the intersection of two sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882097/how-to-calculate-the-intersection-of-two-sets)

Answer (score 0):

```
c1.stream().filter(c2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());//Last step is optional. Only use it, if you want a list of it.
```

`stream()`: Create a stream out of the first collection. (Java 8+)

Then `filter()` by those that are in c2,too.

And then optionally make a list from it.