# Find out whether two HashSets have a duplicate value

Tags: java, hashset

I need a function like the following,

```
boolean hasDuplicateValue(HashSet hs1, HashSet hs2) {        
    // return false;
}
```

This thread [Efficiently finding the intersection of a variable number of sets of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851938/efficiently-finding-the-intersection-of-a-variable-number-of-sets-of-strings) discusses a similar issue, however in this thread they also need the intersection values, which I do not need. So, it may add an additional computational complexity which I do not need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `java.util.Collections` class provides useful methods for that:

```
boolean hasDuplicateValue(HashSet hs1, HashSet hs2) {        
  return !Collections.disjoint(hs1,hs2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure but do you talking about something like this ?

```
boolean hasDuplicateValue(HashSet hs1, HashSet hs2) {
    // you can add some null pointer defence if necessary
    if (hs2.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (Object obj : hs1) {
        if (hs2.contains(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: just a note, if hs2 size is zero then he can return false immediately

Comment: better use generics: `HashSet<?>`

Comment: @upog even better: always iterate over the smaller set

Comment: @Jan Dvorak in that case, the contains method need to iterate over the larger collection. so i doubt in this case whether it will improve performance ....

Comment: @upog do you know how hash sets work? Lookup is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [guava-libraries](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained?tm=6) that provide a [Sets](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) which contains the intersect method. On the other side, this method takes two Set, not their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To complete oleg.lukyrych answer:
If you want to remove the warnings, on the declaration of the method:
And it is a good practice to use Set instead of HashSet when possible :

```
<T> boolean hasDuplicateValue(Set<T> hs1, Set<T> hs2) {
    for (T obj : hs1) {
        if (hs2.contains(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Good advice. I just took the method signature from question body. Thought it would be most relevant :)