# Java HashSet<String> collision of object

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I am using `HashSet<String>` to store values but some of String has the same hash code. How HashSet handles collision.

```
List<ClassA> getValuesFromA(){

}

List<ClassA> getValuesFromB(){

}

Set <String> a = new HashSet<String>(getValuesFromA()); // data overwritten due to hash code collision

Set <String> b = new HashSet<String>(getValuesFromB()); // data overwritten due to hash code collision

a.removeAll(b);
a.stream().forEach(t -> t.setSomeValue(X));
b.addAll(a);
```

I am using HashSet to find a minus b in O(1) for each element and then b + (a - b). But while storing data in HashSet some of the data are overwritten. Has anyone any idea to perform this operation without changing the hash method or data structure?

Comment: "But while storing data in HashSet I lost some of the data." Please be much clearer. Note that hash code collisions *don't* lose data - they just make it slightly less efficient to find values. Please provide a [mcve] as your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: (You probably just want to use `retainAll`, btw.)

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851938/efficiently-finding-the-intersection-of-a-variable-number-of-sets-of-strings

Answer (score 0):

> But while storing data in HashSet I lost some of the data. How to
>   handle this?

Collision in `hashCode()` result will not loose or overwrite an object with the same hashcode in the HashSet.
Two objects with the same hashcode can be stored in a same HashSet.

In your sample code, you do that :

```
Set <String> a = new HashSet<String>(getValuesFromA());

Set <String> b = new HashSet<String>(getValuesFromB());

a.removeAll(b);
```

From `a` you remove all values contained in `b`.
So `a` will contains `a` minus b `values`.
You do an exclusion.

Then you do :

```
b.addAll(a);
```

It is not an intersection as you add to `b` only `a` values that are **not** contained in `b`.

You should rather use the `retainAll()` method as suggested by Jon Skeet and that seems to suit to your requirement :

> Retains only the elements in this set that are contained in the
>   specified collection

```
Set<String> intersectionSet = new HashSet<>(getValuesFromA());    

intersectionSet.retainAll(getValuesFromB());
```