# Find the item that is in each list

Tags: java, list, set

I want to point to the item that is on each list. Lists are kept in List <Set >.
The point is, in each of the lists, it stores several numbers.
I want to add to qSE the numbers that will appear in each of the lists.
What should I add in the code to make it work as it should?

```
public static Set<Integer> getSameElements(List<Set<Integer>> listOfElements){
    Set<Integer> gSE = new HashSet<>();
    for (Set<Integer> list : listOfElements){
        for (int number : list){

            }
        }
    }
    return gSE;
}
```

Comment: No idea what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: Its sounds like you want the intersection of your sets. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851938/efficiently-finding-the-intersection-of-a-variable-number-of-sets-of-strings

Comment: The point is, in each of the lists, it stores several numbers.
I want to add to qSE the numbers that will appear in each of the lists.

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
public static Set<Integer> getSameElements(List<Set<Integer>> listOfElements){
    Set<Integer> gSE = new HashSet<>();
    for (Set<Integer> list : listOfElements){
        for (int number : list){
//this part here\/
               gSE.add(number);

            }
        }
    }
    return gSE;
}
```

may be what youre looking for? if youre trying to put the numbers from the other sets into that set. question is a tad hard to follow but hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that gSE will have to find the numbers that are in each of the lists. If each list contains the digit 1, then gSE is supposed to contain only the digit 1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Integer> list1=Set.of(5,7,9,11,13);
        Set<Integer> list2=Set.of(5,7,9,11,13);
        Set<Integer> list3=Set.of(2,4,6,8,10);
        Set<Integer> list4=Set.of(3,6,9,12,15);
        List<Set<Integer>> addlist=List.of(list1,list2,list3,list4);
        Set<Integer> gse = new HashSet<>();
        for(Set<Integer> s:addlist) {
            for(int n:s ) {
                gse.add(n);
            }
        }
Output:[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15]
```